# How can I remove a button on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, actionlistener

```
var color_arr = ["red","blue","red","blue","red","blue"];
var html = "";
for(var i = 0; i < color_arr.length; i++) {
    html += "<button id='user_color_"+i +"' class='btn' style='background:"+ color_arr[i] +"'></button>";
}
$("#somelement").append(html);
```

So if a user clicks on an button than that button must be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#somelement button").on("click",RemoveElement);

function RemoveElement() {
    $(this).remove();
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yoxkscpm/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#somelement").on('click','.btn',function(){    
 var btnId = $(this).attr("id");
 $("#"+btnId).remove();    
});
```

but you better add new class and change .btn with it.

Comment: Why would you use the id when you already have the object itself?

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes of your code. Your `var html` variable has removed.

You can use `$(...).click(...`

```js
var color_arr = ["red","blue","red","blue","red","blue"];

for(var i = 0; i < color_arr.length; i++) {
  $("#somelement").append("<button id='user_color_"+i +"' class='btn' style='background:"+ color_arr[i] +"'>Button</button>");
}
$("#somelement button").click(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="somelement"></div>
```